# Proxy Git SSH into Gitlab container

Tags: docker, ssh, configuration, gitlab, gitlab-omnibus

I'm currently setting up a gitlab omnibus container, and I'm trying to forward SSH into the container by creating a script that will proxy every command into the container.

The file in `\home\git\gitlab-bash\bin\gitlab-bash` containing the following instruction :

```
#!/bin/sh
# Proxy SSH requests to docker container
sudo docker exec -i -u git gitlab.web.1 /bin/sh -c "SSH_CONNECTION='$SSH_CONNECTION' SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND='$SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND' $0 $1"
```

This was working fine at the begining, but when I updated the gitlab docker image, it begins to trigger the following error:

```
/bin/sh: 1: /home/git/gitlab-shell/bin/gitlab-shell: not found
```

However, if I execute the command in ssh with the git user, it is working fine.
I tried the `-t`option, but no luck, I have

`the input device is not a TTY`

The git user in host and gitlab have the same uid & gid

The git user (host) has it's home directory in gitlab data directory for authorized_keys to work.

I am using key authentification.